# Check User Existance in Parse to Automate the Login

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to check if the user has logged on before, using Parse and if they have, it should take them to MainForm but if not, it should take the user to LoginForm.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrent();
    if (currentUser != null) {

        new MainForm(theme).show();

    } else {

        new LoginForm(theme).show();
    }
```

But it gives me errors, I don't know what am I doing wrong, Please help.

Comment: Scott's answer is good. If you want a parse specific question I would suggest adding a parse4cn1 tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered just saving the user information to the preferences?

From the chat app demo project: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-2.html

```
    // if the user already logged in previously and we have a token
    String t = Preferences.get(tokenPrefix + "token", (String)null);
    if(t != null) {
        // we check the expiration of the token which we previously stored as System time
        long tokenExpires = Preferences.get(tokenPrefix + "tokenExpires", (long)-1);
        if(tokenExpires < 0 || tokenExpires > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            // we are still logged in
            showContactsForm(data);
            return;
        }
    }
```